# Message queue for IPC with fork and want to know whether the processes 'share' the message buffer or just copy and 'show' to the other process

Tags: c, fork, ipc, message-queue

I am student and was programming with fork() in C for multi-process matrix multiplication.

but while I was doing this, I had question about
when we use IPC with MESSAGE QUEUE, then,
If I put

```
struct message_buffer{
long mtype;
int result[100][100];
}
```

like this, 
 I know this is not efficient because the space is copied all the time as message but... 
I thought that is the only way all processes can share result table....(is there another way?)

anyway If I put the result array table like that, 
then in where memory place the result table is created??...

they create the place in kernel place and REALLY 'share' that place but with the abstraction as message?

or

the message buffer are created in one main process and not share, but just copy and show to the other process.

pleaseeeeee give me a tip :'( really want to know....

and if they don`t share the message buffer, then how can I make the processes 'share' the common place?

thank you......

Comment: You should consider using threads.  They share global variables and communication between threads is much easier